# Set mongoose global options in @nestjs/mongoose

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

Mongoose document says we can set global options like `mongoose.set('returnOriginal', false)`.

Now I am using @nestjs/mongoose in nestjs, but I can't find a document describes how to do this global options setting.

I do find a way to change the setting by `InjectConnection`

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule, InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
...
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('DB_URI'),
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
      }),
    }),
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private readonly connection: Connection) {
    connection.base.set('returnOriginal', false);
  }
}
```

This code works fine for me. However in `@types/mongoose`, there is no property `base.set` in type `Connection`. I have to omit the type definition for injected `connection`.

My question is whether this is a standard approach to set mongoose global options? If not, how can I do this?

Comment: Yes, def some documentation issues on NestJs' end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since package `mongoose` is installed, I can just directly set the option.

```js
...
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
...
mongoose.set('returnOriginal', false);

@Model({...})
export class AppModule {...}
```